# Trying konlpy, but getting a runtime error relating to jpype

Tags: python, nlp, jpype

I'm trying to use konlpy on Python 3

After installing it, and then running the below (as per documentation examples)

```
from konlpy.tag import Hannanum
hannanum = Hannanum()
```

I get the follow error:

```
RuntimeError: First paramter must be a string or unicode at native\python\jpype_module.cpp:37
```